# An error has occurred when creating debian packaging

Tags: package-management, application-development, quickly, share

i execute quickly share and i get

```
Launchpad connection is ok
........
Command returned some WARNINGS:
----------------------------------
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
mangar/.bzr/README
mangar/.bzr/branch-format
mangar/.bzr/branch/branch.conf
mangar/.bzr/branch/format
mangar/.bzr/branch/last-revision
mangar/.bzr/branch/tags
mangar/.bzr/checkout/conflicts
mangar/.bzr/checkout/dirstate
mangar/.bzr/checkout/format
mangar/.bzr/checkout/views
mangar/.bzr/repository/format
mangar/.bzr/repository/pack-names
----------------------------------
An error has occurred when creating debian packaging
ERROR: can't create or update ubuntu package
ERROR: share command failed
Aborting
```

the previous time i run the command everything worked! the previous time i was using ubuntu but now i am using linux mint 13...
i get the same error with quickly package! i need to package my app for the contest..

edit: now i get this too

```
----------------------------------
ERROR: Python module helpers not found
ERROR: Python module Window not found
ERROR: Python module mangarconfig not found
ERROR: Python module Builder not found
```

those files exist in the package_lib folder, why it cannot find them?

Comment: You might be affected by this problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems with Quickly, could you try the next?

- Rename your folder.
- Create again the project with quickly.
- Copy all files from the renamed folder to the new project.
- Try again ;)

Between the 2º and 3º step you must configure the branch:

```
quickly configure bzr lp:~launchpadUserName/launchpadProject/trunk
quickly configure ppa launchpadUserName/launchpadProject
```